# save a result to use it again in an sql query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT (A+B)*C whole, (A+B)*C/2 half FROM MY_TABLE
```

Do I have any way to save the result of (A+B)*C, so the sql db will not have to calculate it twice?

Comment: reminds me of this -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: @davidkonrad Different story...The query cache stores the result of whole queries, not of column (calculations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can store the result in a variable.

```
SELECT @whole := (A+B)*C whole, @whole / 2 half 
FROM MY_TABLE
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @whole := null) var_init_subquery
```

But I doubt, this will speed anything up (significantly). Like I said in your other question, this kind of "optimizations" should be the least of your concerns (if at all).